# (Nonconnective algebraic) K-theory cohomology = K-theory of cohomology?

Tags: stable-homotopy, algebraic-k-theory

#### Situation

Suppose that we have

- a commutative ring (or an $E_{\infty}$-ring) $R$ and
- a homotopy type $X$.

Then we get a canonical morphism
$$
f \colon K(R ^ {\Sigma ^ \infty X_+}) \to K(R) ^ {\Sigma ^ \infty X_+}
$$
where $K$ denotes the **nonconnective** algebraic $K$-theory.

#### Question

Is $f$ an equivalence for example when $X$ is finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is typically going to be no.

Suppose for example that $R$ is discrete. Then $R^{\Sigma^\infty_+X}= C^*(X;R)$ is the usual cochain algebra, and perfect modules over that algebra are equivalent (via the homotopy fixed points functor) to the thick full stable subcategory of $Fun(X, Perf(R))$ generated by $R$ as a trivial local coefficient system.

Let's further assume that $R$ is regular noetherian so that $Perf(R)$ has the (bounded) Postnikov $t$-structure, and $Fun(X,Perf(R))$ has the pointwise $t$-structure. This pointwise $t$-structure is inherited by the full subcategory described above. Indeed, I claim that under these assumptions, a local system $L$ is in this thick subcategory if and only if each homotopy group $\pi_kL$, as a $\pi_1(X)$-module, has a filtration whose associated graded's are trivial $\pi_1(X)$-modules - this condition is obviously preserved under truncations.

It follows that the heart of this $t$-structure on this full subcategory is exactly finitely generated $R$-modules, so by the theorem of the heart, $K(C^*(X;R)) = K(R)$, where of course $K(R)^{\Sigma^\infty_+X}$ is usually not $K(R)$ (for instance if $X = S^n$, then $\pi_0$ of the former has a summand isomorphic to $\pi_n$ of the latter)

Comment: Does $K(R)^{\Sigma_+^\infty X}$ correspond to the K-theory of $\operatorname{Fun}(X,\operatorname{Perf}(R))$? It seems that [Karoubi, *Homologique cyclique*, §3 Définition de la $K$-théorie algébrique en termes de fibrés plats] is doing something similar, but I don't know the precise statement for perfect complexes.

Comment: @Z.M : no, typically not. For instance if $R= \mathbb F_p, X = BG$ for $G$ a finite $p$-group, then $Fun(BG, Perf(R)) = Perf(C^*(BG, \mathbb F_p))$ and so we also get $K(\mathbb F_p)$ in the end. More generally, $K(Fun(BG,Perf(R)))$ is related to the representation theory of $G$ in $R$ (think $R=\mathbb C$ also if that helps), which is not controlled by $K(R)^{BG}$ (it's more closely related to the free loop space of $X$ than $X$ itself, although I can't give you a precise statement yet)

Comment: (I'll let you generalize the slogan to $X$ not equal to $BG$, but the point is that they are typically different)

Comment: (But of course they're related by a comparison map, and it's really interesting to try and understand how far it is from being an equivalence - for $X=BG,$ G$ finite this is typically something that "completion theorems" try to do)

Comment: $BG$ does not seem to be finite (it is "almost compact") in general. I do not know whether it affects.

Comment: @Z.M no it is not compact, I was answering a more general question. But the answer is typically still no in the compact case (although we have less tools to adress "how far it is from an equivalence") - consider for instance $X= S^1$. Then $K(Fun(S^1, Perf(R)) = KAut(R)$. Take for instance $R=$ an algebraically closed field $k$. Then $Fun(S^1,Perf(k))$ can still be described in terms of eigenvalues: it is a direct sum over $\lambda\in k^\times$ of $Perf(k)$'s, whereas $K(k)^{S^1}= \Omega K(k) \oplus K(k)$

Comment: (the point is that $Fun(X,Perf(R))$ is the "representation theory" of $\Omega X$, so the finiteness of $X$ doesn't play a huge role)

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Karoubi considered the equivalence classes of acyclic maps $Y\to X$ along with a local system in finite projective $R$-modules on $Y$, equipped with a monoidal structure, then consider its group completion. He proved that this coincides with the homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $K(R)$. This is of course closely related to the plus construction, but is this extra $Y$ playing some role to compare the two?

Comment: @Z.M : the result is wrong without these $Y$'s, so I would guess that it does play a role, yes. Again, it's not very hard to check, even on $\pi_0$, that this cannot work, even for the simple example of $S^1$ and $R =\mathbb C$ (not topologized) (and without invoking perfect of course, this works for projective things as well).

Comment: Karoubi also says it : "Les considérations précédentes montrent qu'il est vain  de tenter de définir $K_A(X)$ en termes de fibrés plats sur $X$"

Comment: The (maybe intuitively surprising) point is that even if $F$ has no homology, $Fun(F, D(\mathbb Z))$ can be interesting ! (again, it's more about $\Omega F$ than about $F$). For instance there are acyclic groups of infinite cohomological dimension.

Comment: Right, I've just skimmed Karoubi's proof, and I can't say I understand it without actually reading it but that seems to be exactly the point : maps $X\to BGL(A)^+ $ will lift to $BGL(A)$ essentially uniquely if one is willing to change $X$ to an acyclic cover. The point is basically that your universal choice is the pullback $X\times_{BGL(A)^+}BGL(A)$. There are technical details to extract a proof from that but that seems to be the main idea

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly thought that group completion of a sheaf of monoids commute with taking global sections if the base is compact Hausdorff.